# How to add 2 images below one another in ImageView JavaFx?

Tags: java, image, javafx

I want to add 2 photos in 2 imageviews one after another and below another. but when I am adding the Hbox() they are showing side by side. How I trigger ImageView 2 to show below Imageview1?

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Image image = new Image("imageresource/Tagline.jpg");

        ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(image);
            imageView1.setFitHeight(100);
            imageView1.setPreserveRatio(true);
        Image image2 = new Image("imageresource/main.jpg");
        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image2);
        imageView2.setFitHeight(200);
        imageView2.setPreserveRatio(true);



        HBox hbox = new HBox();
            hbox.getChildren().addAll(imageView1,imageView2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: Use a VBox. H stands for horizontal and V for vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a VBox. The HBox displays its childs horizontally, as the name suggests.